# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in kotlin

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, exception

I'm trying to make a function but sometimes throws a `java.util.concurrentmodificationexception` (sometimes not). Here is my code:

```
Thread(Runnable {
                        try {
                            var str = URL("https://server.necrodragon41.repl.co/server/anime/$email/$pass/${list[numb].link.replace("//", "/")}").readText(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))

                            var ngson = GsonBuilder().create()

                            var t = ngson.fromJson(str, Anime::class.java)

                            try {
                                var si = t.description.take(297) + "..."
                                runOnUiThread {
                                    var intent = Intent(this, AnimeDataActivity::class.java).apply {
                                        putExtra("title", list[numb].title)
                                        putExtra("link", list[numb].link)
                                        putExtra("description", si)
                                    }
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                }
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                var si = t.description
                                runOnUiThread {
                                    var intent = Intent(this, AnimeDataActivity::class.java).apply {
                                        putExtra("title", list[numb].title)
                                        putExtra("link", list[numb].link)
                                        putExtra("description", si)
                                    }
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            runOnUiThread {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Error getting json file.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                        }
                    }).start()
```

I've seen that others that had the same problem was because they were modificationg a list in a for loop, but i'm not.

It throws an error when accessing from inside the `runOnUiThread`, line of the first `putExtra` inside the declaration of the variable `intent`. What I don't know is why i get an error only there and not where the variable `str` is declared, if it also uses the `list` variable.

Ay ideas?

Comment: Do a bit of reading about thread safety, some info here [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html). Also, some info on what line the error is thrown is needed.

Comment: @Alex.T I've done it but I cannot find why it throws the error on the putExtra and not on the url.readtext